# Bootstrap modal height as per window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make modal height same as window height. The height of the modal is then dynamic, expanding to fit the content appropriately, up to 90% of the window height. Also want to left out some space top of the screen to show the header.

This is what i have written:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var modalObj = $(this).find('.modal-content');                                        
        if ($(modalObj).height() > ($(window).height()*0.8)) {
            $(modalObj).height($(window).height()*0.8);
        }                                         
    });
 })
```

Problem is when i switch the device from portrait to landscape or vice versa, on the first attempt modal gets height of previous mode.

Lets say i open the modal on portait mode and it is shwoing 430px of height. Than i closed the modal i switch the device to landscape and open the modal, it shows 430px(height that were coming on portait mode) but if i again open the modal, it gets the correct height.

I think when i close the modal the height didn't get remove. I have to write something that clear the height every time i close the modal or resize the window.

Also tried:

```
var callback = function () {

  $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var modalObj = $(this).find('.modal-content');                                      
        if ($(modalObj).height() > ($(window).height()*0.9)) {
            $(modalObj).height($(window).height()*0.9);
        }                                         
    });
};

$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);
```

Comment: You want the modal to be 90% of the viewport height?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want the modal to consume 90% of the viewport height, you don't need any JS. CSS has a special unit for that called `vh`. `100vh` is 100% of the viewport.

In your case, you'll just need:

```
.modal {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

You can also change it to `max-height` if necessary.

Comment: Thats a good way to keep the height of modal container less than window width. But i have to calulate the modal-content height on run time to apply the scroll bar if needed.

Comment: using this:
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                                        $(this).find('.modal-content').height($(window).height()*0.9);
                                    });

Comment: Again, you don't need the JS, the code I gave you does the same thing as your JS and updates with every change of the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

Your callback function changes the handler for the `shown.bs.modal` event. If your modal is already open this handler has already been executed and will not trigger again in window resize.

You need a different handler for the `window.resize` event.

```
// This will detect and set the height properly when the modal opens
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var modalObj = $(this).find('.modal-content');
    $(modalObj).height('auto');
    if ($(modalObj).height() > ($(window).height() * 0.9)) {
        $(modalObj).height($(window).height() * 0.9);
    }
});

// This will detect and set the height properly when the window resizes
var callback = function () {
    jQuery('.modal').each(function (idx, item) {
        var modalObj = $(item).find('.modal-content');
        $(modalObj).height('auto');
        if ($(modalObj).height() > ($(window).height() * 0.9)) {
            $(modalObj).height($(window).height() * 0.9);
        }
    });
};

// Binding the callback in document.ready is not required, just on window.resize
$(window).resize(callback);
```

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/w6jdqu9ODm) is a demo in Bootply.

Answer (score 3):

Actually we need to use height to `.modal-body` along with `overflow-y: auto` property, not to `.modal`. But first we need to leave some space for `.modal-header` and `.modal-footer`. So, I am using 75% for `.modal-body` and 25% leaving for `.modal-header` and `.modal-footer`. You can adjust it as per your needs

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: 75vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Or if you want to adjust in pixels

```
.modal-body {
   max-height: calc(100vh - 180px); // to adjust you can change 180px
   overflow-y: auto;
   }
```